# Can Apscheduler run two jobs with same cron trigger?

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

Will using sched.add_job with same time and date trigger for two different jobs run both of them? 
If not, how can I add the second job with a different trigger time using the same Background scheduler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223222/how-do-i-schedule-an-interval-job-with-apscheduler>

Answer (score 1):

You can use apscheduler to execute two jobs at the same time:

```
from flask import Flask
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def job1():
    for _ in range(1000):
        print('a')

def job2():
    for _ in range(1000):
        print('b')

h = 10 
m = 0
# set h,m to the time you are ready to test

scheduler.add_job(job1,'cron',hour=h,minute=m)
scheduler.add_job(job2,'cron',hour=h,minute=m)
scheduler.start()
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def my_task1():
    print ("Task 1")
def my_task2():
    print ("Task 2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   process_scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
   process_scheduler.add_job(my_task1, 'cron', id='my_task1', seconds=5)
   process_scheduler.add_job(my_task2, 'cron', id='my_task2', seconds=10)
   process_scheduler.start()
   atexit.register(lambda: process_scheduler.shutdown())
```